# Convert a data frame with 2 columns to only one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
gous <- structure(list(V1 = c(0, 28.44), V2 = c(1, 28.44), V3 = c(2, 
                                                                  28.44), V4 = c(3, 28.39), V5 = c(4, 28.22), V6 = c(5, 27.72), 
                       V7 = c(6, 24.56), V8 = c(7, 18.78), V9 = c(8, 18.5), V10 = c(9, 
                                                                                    18.56), V11 = c(10, 18.5), V12 = c(11, 18.72)), .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                                                                               "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
                                                                                                                                               "V12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

The data is as follows:

```
> gous
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8   V9   V10  V11   V12
1  0.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.0  9.00 10.0 11.00
2 28.44 28.44 28.44 28.39 28.22 27.72 24.56 18.78 18.5 18.56 18.5 18.72
```

I want to convert the data to following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
28.44
28.44
28.44
28.39
28.22
27.72
24.56
18.78
18.5
18.56
18.5
18.72
```

What I tried:
I tried to separate the two rows of data into individual vectors as follows:

```
gous1 <- as.numeric(gous[1,])
gous2 <- as.numeric(gous[2,])
```

But I was unable to combine using `rbind` or `cbind`. What is the function that I am looking at here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `c`, i.e. `c(gous1, gous2)`. You can also just do `as.vector(t(gous))` to achieve the same output.

Answer (score 5):

I'd try `t` and `c`:

```
c(t(gous))

## > c(t(gous) )
##  [1]  0.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 10.00 11.00
## [13] 28.44 28.44 28.44 28.39 28.22 27.72 24.56 18.78 18.50 18.56 18.50 18.72
```

Comment: Wins the r-golf challenge for sure.

Comment: If you did want it as a column then you could: `stack(data.frame(t(gous)))[,1, drop=FALSE]`

Answer (score 2):

The `c()` command will concatenate two vectors into one:

```
c(as.numeric(gous[1,]),as.numeric(gous[2,]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c(apply(gous, 1, c))
 [1]  0.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 10.00 11.00 28.44 28.44 28.44 28.39
 [17] 28.22 27.72 24.56 18.78 18.50 18.56 18.50 18.72
```

If you want to see it displayed vertically try:

```
 as.matrix( c(apply(gous, 1, c)) )
```

Could also use:

```
c( matrix(unlist(gous), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```